# Is there a function in R which checks if two XStrings have matching substrings of some size (n) in corresponding positions

Tags: r, string, substring

I am trying to determine if two XStrings of equal length have the same substring of some given length in the corresponding positions.
Is there a built-in function in R for this problem?

Let's say I have strings

```
a <- "AACCT**GCCCGGAA**CCT" ,  
b <- "CCATC**GCCCGGAA**CCT"
```

and given length is 8
I need a function `fun(a,b,len=8)` that would return `TRUE` or possibly even a position where such a substring first occurs.

Of course, real strings that I am using are much longer and the given length of substring may not be 8 all the time.

This could be done by for lops but it would be preferred not to use them

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by splitting the strings into individual characters, testing equality of the resulting vectors, and performing run-length encoding on the logical vector produced:

```r
f <- function(a, b, n) {
   rl <- rle(strsplit(a, "")[[1]] == strsplit(b, "")[[1]])
   ind <- which(rl$values == TRUE & rl$lengths >= n)[1]
   cumsum(rl$lengths[seq(ind - 1)]) + 1
}
```

This will tell you the first position in the strings where there are at least `n` parallel matching bases:

```r
f(a, b, 8)
#> [1] 6
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rleid`

```
library(data.table)
Map(function(u, v) {i1 <- u == v
   grp <- rleid(i1); which(i1  & ave(seq_along(grp), grp, 
        FUN = length) >= 8)[1]},
       strsplit(a, ""), strsplit(b, ""))[[1]]
#[1] 6
```